# Force measurement on grab bars

Tags: sensors, force

I recently start a project to measure the force on a bathroom grab bar. The force/load is applied by the person who need to the grab bar for assistant. What I want to measure is the load against the wall and do the the real-time monitoring of the load for further analysis to improve the design.

I am not quite sure about what kind of sensor would be suitable to do the measurement. I am looking at different load cells but cannot get the idea how to mount commercial load cells to do the measurement. What I am trying right now is using strain gauge to measure the strain near the end of the bar(wall side) and roughly calculate the load. I think (might be wrong) there may exists some kind of force/load sensors that can clamp on the bar to do the measurement.

Any sensor types/models or suggestion are welcome.

I also posted this question to EE forum
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/57197/how-to-measure-force-that-applied-on-grab-bar

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting your question. This is not directly robotics related but I believe the community of roboticists might have some insights into this, given the varied backgrounds. You might also find [Electrical Eng SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) useful. In addition, I would _highly_ recommend you check out the [Mech Eng SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44908/mechanical-engineering). Hope someone here can help you!

Comment: This may be better off on [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/), but I'm happy to leave it here to see if it gets any traction here. If you *do* post this question to *EE* then please link to this question and edit this question to point to the question on *EE*. Thanks,

Comment: Since this now has [answers over on Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/57197/3774), I'm going to close this one as off-topic, since it isn't really a *robotics* question. I assume it will be closed as a duplicate there.